# What does this announcement about free, public CVs really mean?

Tags: discussion, jobs

> As a part of careers, we’re planning
> to roll out free, public CVs with
> user-selectable “vanity” URLs in a
> week or two. In retrospect, we should
> have done this from day one, as it
> compliments the public record of your
> Q&A on Stack Overflow. As Joel notes,
> the best way to control your online
> presence is to fill it yourself with
> all the cool stuff you’ve been doing!
> Don’t let others tell the story of you
> when you can tell it yourself. --[StackOverflow Podcast 70 Summary](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2009/10/podcast-70/)

I haven't listened to the podcast yet, but could someone elaborate? After reading this, it seems like everyone will get a CV that they can attach to their profile without paying a cent. However, these won't be in the careers searchable database unless you pay the fee. Is this correct?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There will be a tab titled **publish cv** containing:

```
Your CV is private; make it public to the world

http://careers.stackoverflow.com/[ input box ]
```

Below that will be individual per-field toggles to hide things you don't want shown to the public. This should be available by the 27th and we will make sure to allow a brief period where current paid members can get the public URLs they want first.

Answer (score 2):

Everything that I have seen up to this point leads me to believe that you can fill out a CV but you are paying a fee to have it filed and searchable by prospective employers.

Comment: But this announcement calls it a public CV. I'm really hoping that means that even if it's not filed and searchable, I can still link people to it and be like "hey, look at this" and that if someone goes to my SO profile, they can click on a link and jump to it. That would really rock.

Comment: @Thomas Owens: That's what I was trying to say. You will be able to post a public CV but it wouldn't be included in search results or something.

Comment: I think the only way for someone to find your "public CV" is if you put a link on your blog/website pointing to it.