# How do I pick the vanity url for my stack overflow careers cv?

Tags: support, status-completed, jobs

Joel mentioned on the podcast that we’d be able to pick a vanity URL for our Stack Overflow Careers CV.

I can’t see anywhere to set that.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This feature is now live; check the "Publish CV" tab.

Answer (score 5):

You would be able to...

That doesn't mean you are able to...yet.

Answer (score 0):

Aha, also see the accepted answer to [this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/26162/).