# Autosave of vanity url on Careers is too fast

Tags: support, status-completed, jobs, usability

I just tried to [pick a vanity url for my public CV](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/26451/how-do-i-pick-the-vanity-url-for-my-stack-overflow-careers-cv/27580#27580), and I find that it auto-saves too quickly.

I wanted a vanity url like "john-doe".  But if I don't type it fast enough, the auto-save of "john-" removes the trailing hyphen, so when I continue to type I end up with "johndoe".

Note: It is *not* the case that a hyphen is not allowed, because if I type quickly it accepts "john-doe" just fine.  It just doesn't allow a trailing hyphen.

Comment: You should type faster :) Or copy paste the text from an outside source.

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure I agree with this request, as having the delay be too long is definitely worse (as in: your entry may not be saved at all) than having it be too short.

I increased it from 1000ms to 1500ms, but I'm not willing to increase it any further.