# Autosave of vanity URL on Careers moves cursor focus

Tags: bug, status-declined, jobs, usability, focus

Another problem I found with [picking a vanity url for my public CV](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/26451/how-do-i-pick-the-vanity-url-for-my-stack-overflow-careers-cv/27580#27580) on Careers: the auto-save always moves the cursor to the end of the line.  This makes it very disruptive to change the url.  Say I used "jdoe" and wanted to change it to "johndoe".  I might end up with "jodoehn" or "johdoen", depending on how quickly I can type.

Answer (score 1):

Minor, doesn't happen in Firefox 3.5 (though I can repro it in Chrome), and should be resolved by the other request you made.

[Autosave of vanity url on Careers is too fast](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/27583/autosave-of-vanity-url-on-careers-is-too-fast)

Comment: it happened to me in FF 3.5 ...